# What are the important methods that evolved in computing optical flow?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I have gone through various approaches to find optical flow. But I have a tad confusion between Horn and Shunck method and Lucas Kannede method. Where are these methods useful and where do these methods fail? What can be the next approach to deal them?